# Create a Flattened record from source table data

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a SQL statement that will create a flattened table from source table data. This is what I am trying to do :

- get the status and sum of its quantity for a combination of orderid, partid

I tried to accomplish this with the following query based on case expression:

```
SELECT orderid, partid, 
       SUM(quantity) as total,
       status1 =  case [status] when 1 then SUM(quantity) else null end,
       status2 =  case [status] when 2 then SUM(quantity) else null end,
       status3 =  case [status] when 3 then SUM(quantity) else null end 
FROM   partsum
GROUP BY  orderid,
          partid,
          status;
```

But the results are not what I require. I know I am grouping with status but the query will not compile without adding it to the list.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to write this.  Also I converted your nulls to zeros, but it could be easy enough to switch them back to nulls if that's what you really need.  You didn't specify whic version of SQL, so here are two solutions that will work:

A SQL 2005+ Version:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        OrderID, 
        PartID,
        SUM(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY PartID) as Total,
        SUM( case [status] when 1 then quantity else 0 end) 
                OVER (Partition By PartID) as Status1,
        SUM( case [status] when 2 then quantity else 0 end) 
                OVER (Partition By PartID) as Status2,
        SUM( case [status] when 3 then quantity else 0 end) 
                OVER (Partition By PartID)as Status3
FROM    PartSum
```

Should work on any version (and by any i mean at least back to SQL 6.5):

```
SELECT  
        OrderID, 
        PartID,
        SUM(Quantity) as Total,
        SUM( case [status] when 1 then quantity else 0 end) as Status1,
        SUM( case [status] when 2 then quantity else 0 end) as Status2,
        SUM( case [status] when 3 then quantity else 0 end) as Status3
FROM    PartSum
GROUP BY  orderid,
          partid
```

Comment: @ the second one worked for me. First one- because of my lack of experience in T-SQL- could not get to group records ( in my actual code). I will need to study Over and Partition by to better understand.  Can we use group by and, OVER & PARTITION at the same time?

Comment: The first one used DISTINCT and won't work in it's current form with a group by.

Comment: @EBarr- My confusion is actually on whether PartitionBy PartID  do a grouping on all other rows in the select statement?

Comment: @EBarr- I did miss to add DISTINCT key word on actual query I was executing. I will try again

Comment: You can use GROUP BY and PARTITION in the same query, just not the way I wrote the one above.  GROUP BY collapses rows together, PARTITION BY performs an aggregation over a segment of data.  This discussion may help you ... http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12784/sql-server-difference-between-partition-by-and-group-by

Comment: the link helped - especially answer by 'adolf garlic' about repeating data

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Order].OrderID,
    [Order].PartID,
    [Order].Total,
    Status1.Status AS Status1,
    Status2.Status AS Status2,
    Status3.Status AS Status3
FROM 
    (SELECT OrderID, PartID, SUM(Quantity) AS Total
        FROM PartSum
        GROUP BY OrderID, PartID) [Order]
    LEFT JOIN PartSum Status1 ON [Order].OrderID = Status1.OrderID AND [Order].PartID = Status1.PartID AND Status1.Status = 1
    LEFT JOIN PartSum Status2 ON [Order].OrderID = Status2.OrderID AND [Order].PartID = Status2.PartID AND Status2.Status = 2
    LEFT JOIN PartSum Status3 ON [Order].OrderID = Status3.OrderID AND [Order].PartID = Status2.PartID AND Status3.Status = 3
```

This is assuming you have a fixed number of possible status codes.

Comment: Thank you. your answer did work ( I  added Distinct key word). I was looking to do it with case as in 2nd option of EBarr.